# Como listar apenas a imagem destacada de um post?

Tags: php, html5, wordpress

Como posso mostrar em minha página, apenas as imagens destacadas, sem títulos e descrição em minha página?

Esta é minha estrutura:

```
<?php

    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category_name' => 'primeiro-conceito' );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
            $com_number = get_comments_number( $post->ID );
            $post_thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
            $post_thumb_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumb_id, '800x850' );
?>

    <div id="posts-conceitos">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $ultima->ID ); ?>"><img class="img-responsive margin-bottom-10" src="<?php echo $post_thumb_src[0]; ?>"></a>


        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: poste um trecho do código que está utilizando, a sua pergunta abre portas para respostas muito amplas.

Comment: segue meu código:

Comment: Não vejo "títulos e descrição" no código que está mostrando...

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazê-lo desta maneira:

```
<?php
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
echo $thumb_url[0];
?>
```

Certifica-te de trocar o `thumbnail-size` pelos tamanhos especificados abaixo, para modificar o tamanho das imagens.

Os tamanhos padrão disponíveis são - `thumbnail`, `medium`, `large` e `full`.